# Firestore security rules when accessing new doc in transaction?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am running the following Firestore transaction to create a new document in an `accounts` collection and add its newly-created ID to the user's `accounts`. (Conversely, the `members` object sent to the account contains the user ID.)

```
db.runTransaction(transaction => {
    return transaction.get(db.collection('accounts').doc())
        .then(res => {
            const accountId = res.id;
            transaction.set(db.collection('accounts').doc(accountId), {name, numberOfEmployees, businessTypes, industry, members})
            transaction.set(db.collection('users').doc(uid), {accounts: {[accountId]: true}}, {merge: true})
            return accountId;
        }, error => error)
})
```

I am using the fact that `.collection('accounts').doc()` without a path [returns a new document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc), but I am running into the `Missing or insufficient permissions.` error. My rules are as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /accounts/{accountId} {
        // allow read if user is a member or if the document does not exist
        allow read : if resource.data.members[request.auth.uid] == true || !exists(/databases/{database}/documents/accounts/$(accountId));

      // allow update, delete if user is a member
      allow update, delete: if resource.data.members[request.auth.uid] == true;

      // allow creation of any authenticated user
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have already narrowed it down to the `read` rule on `/accounts/{accountId}` (if I set it to `if true;`, it works). What should I set it to to allow access to documents that don't 'exist' yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer by changing the rule to:

```
allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && (resource.data.members[request.auth.uid] == true || resource == null);
```

Comment: This was driving me INSANE! THANK YOU!  Even doing a `! ( 'createdBy' in resource.data )` did not work, i guess because `resource` was null .. but of course there's no way to debug this and figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [getAfter()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.getAfter) in your security rules to obtain the document state as it will be at the end of the transaction (but before it's committed).

So instead of `resource == null`, which can be strange for someone reading the rules, you can use:

```
allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(accountId)).data.members[request.auth.uid] == true;
```